# How to deal with error 403 in Azure data factory with creating datasets?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have enountered several error but non of them appears to be the problem. I have already granted fully access and roles to my account but I keep having these errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same error when Networking is **disabled** in Storage account.

[image]

To resolve this, go to **Storage account -> Networking -> Enabled from all Networks** like below and save it.

[image]

You can see, now I am able to access the files when creating dataset.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rakesh! That was the solution to my problem. Also I would like to ask you if you recognize the error code 20554. It appears when I try to create a dataset connected to DYN365. The details are the following:

The data store endpoint is not supported in 'Dynamics' connector. Error message : 'The domain of this endpoint is not in allow list. Original endpoint: 'proteknica-uat1.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com''
The domain of this endpoint is not in allow list. Original endpoint: 'proteknica-uat1.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com'
Activity ID: cae0bf4c-b412-41bd-974c-c030913e4914

Comment: I think it's better to raise your ask in a new question with proper details, so that the community can assist you.